# Small Machine Translation Model

Tags: machine-translation

I would like to perform Machine Translation in tensorflow.js, in the browser. The issue is that state-of-the-art models have many gigabytes ([fairseq ensemble](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/examples/wmt19/README.md)), and translation is slow.

Do you know some good small models for Machine Translation? Probably something below the 50 million parameter threshold.

I found some older papers with models below 100 MB for training on small datasets ([IWSLT'15 English-Vietnamese attention-based models](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/nmt/)), but these are probably superseded.

Comment: There's a 300MB model in [OpenNMT](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-tf/tree/master/scripts/wmt), which would perhaps be compressed with [ERNIE](https://github.com/robeld/ERNIE). The paper states that 5x compression keeps 98% accuracy.